# Creating Text Boxes based on the value of a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Basically wht I'm trying to do is have a single textbox on a page. When the user enters a number, it should auto generate X amount of additional text boxes below it.

I've been able to get it to work based off of a dropdown box but a dropdown box will not work for this application.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ppl").change(function(){

    // The easiest way is of course to delete all textboxes before adding new ones
    //$("#holder").html("");

    var count = $("#holder input").size();
    var requested = parseInt($("#ppl").val(),10);

    if (requested > count) {
        for(i=count; i<requested; i++) {
        var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:'text'});        
            $("#holder").append($ctrl);
        }
}
    else if (requested < count) {
        var x = requested - 1;
        $("#holder input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
    }
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<SELECT id="ppl">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</SELECT>
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also is there an alternative way to do something like this using ajax rather then jquery?

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsmkn/3/)

Comment: How would AJAX be relevant?

Comment: what do you mean by `using ajax rather then jquery`?

Comment: I would create a text box template that got cloned in a for loop with i set to the input value of your first text box

Comment: What I mean is instead of it dynamically generating the box I'll have user submit his number using xmlhttprequest

Comment: @jimmypage then server have to return the html which will be appended to `#holder`?

Comment: You could have a server script that takes the number as a parameter, and sends back HTML with the box, and you then append that to the DOM.

Comment: @jimmypage IMHO this is the correct way to do it

Comment: The only reason to do it with AJAX is if the contents of the box should contain data that only the server can provide, such as database content.

Comment: Okay so I've modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zsmkn/3/

Comment: With the updated fiddle...how can i give each textbox generated a unique name to use them later in the script?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q5vY4/

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your fiddle again, as your fiddle had everything sitting in the HTML part. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsmkn/4/).

To give them all unique names, all you need to do is concatenate the index (`i`) to the end of the name field like this:

```
for (i = count; i < requested; i++) {
  var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                name: 'text' + i,
                value: 'text'
            });
  $("#holder").append($ctrl);
}
```

This will give you unique names: ("text1", "text2", .. and so on). I have already changed it for you in the updated fiddle.

I'm agreeing with @Barmar when it comes to your AJAX question, there's no point to do an additional server request unless you need to get data which only the server can provide. It just adds another factor into the equation which might slow things down. If JavaScript can do exactly the same for you but then on the client side instead of on the server side, it is definitely a much faster option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar solution.  If you get the desired box count from Ajax then you'll just need to call the 'generateTextBoxes' function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.js"></script>
    <script>
        var generateTextBoxes = function( qty, container ) {
            if (container) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++ ) {
                    $('<label for="box-'+i+'">Box '+i+'</label>&nbsp;<input id="box-'+i+'" name="box-'+i+'" type="text" /><br>').appendTo( container );
                }
            }
        }
        var init = function() {
            $('#btnGenBoxes').on('click', function() {
                generateTextBoxes( $('#box-0').val(), $('#putThemHere') );
            });
        }
        window.onload = init;
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="box-0" />How many?</label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="box-0" name="box-0" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnGenBoxes" value="Generate text boxes" />
    <br><br>
    <div id="putThemHere"></div>

</body>
</html>
```