# give dynamically generated textboxes unique names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a script to dynamically generate X textboxes based on user input. How can I give each textbox their own name so I can use each one individually after they are generated?

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsmkn/3/)

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ppl").change(function(){

    // The easiest way is of course to delete all textboxes before adding new ones
    //$("#holder").html("");

    var count = $("#holder input").size();
    var requested = parseInt($("#ppl").val(),10);

    if (requested > count) {
        for(i=count; i<requested; i++) {
        var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:'text'});        
            $("#holder").append($ctrl);
        }
}
    else if (requested < count) {
        var x = requested - 1;
        $("#holder input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
    }
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <Input type="text" id="ppl">
     <button onclick="function()">Try it</button>       
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ppl").change(function(){

        var count = $("#holder input").size();
        var requested = parseInt($("#ppl").val(),10);

        if (requested > count) {
            for(i=count; i<requested; i++) {
                var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:'text'});        
                $("#holder").append($ctrl);
            }
        } else if (requested < count) {
            var x = requested - 1;
            $("#holder input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

im plan to use the generated textboxes to request more information from user and then use that new information to process another script.

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328719/creating-text-boxes-based-on-the-value-of-a-text-box/16328901#16328901) you are asking the same thing in the end, are you going to ask someone how to read a value from a dynamically generated text box with a unique name next?

Answer (score 0):

Just append the current count to the field name:

```
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text'+i, value:'text'});
```

Comment: Mark, thank you. Once my textboxes are generated...is there a way I can dynamically create another textbox once my text boxes are loaded with a new submit button calling an additional function?

Comment: Sure. In that case you'd probably want to track the count outside the loop so you can reuse it. E.g. initialise `var count=1;` at the beginning, use `name:'text'+count` instead of `name:'text'+i`, and add `count++` whenever you create a text field.

Comment: may be my fiddle code which dynamically add a new table row can be of any help :) each row has different name and id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328743/where-to-call-a-function-in-jquery i guess creating another textbox will just be adding another .append( [your new textbox])?